# Unexpacting error in eclipse on startup: "Unable to acquire application service"

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-10.10

Here is what I got from the Eclipse log when trying to start Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.10:

- My exact Eclipse version is: ***to be filled by the OP***
- My JDK version used to launched Eclipse is: ***to be filled by the OP***

The log:

```
!SESSION 2011-07-11 11:25:12.125 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-07-11 11:25:14.306
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Do you have seen that error before, and how would you troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is like [bug 223756](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=223756), it could be related to where Eclipse has been installed.

> > May be your crash relate to read-only installation? ([bug 216066](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=216066), [bug 225257](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=225257))
>
> Yes, that sounds reasonable. My eclipse installation resides in `/opt/eclipse`,
>   where a 'normal' user doesn't have write access..